# Optimisation Problem Setup and KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, boundary-value-problem, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to setup an optimization problem with equality and inequality constraints.
I want to estimate a specific variable call $\chi$ subject to a minimisation problem -- guidance on the setup and next step to solve it would be helpful. Does it make sense to set the problem up like this? Does a solution exist?  Also in case the KKT conditions do not hold how could I remedy that (i.e. could one change the setup)?

\begin{align*}
    \min_{j,q,b,u} \chi = \frac{1}{u\lambda} * j - 1 \quad \text{s.t.}  \\[0.5cm]
    \text{s.t.}\quad
   j + q - \epsilon\kappa b &= \alpha u \\
    \dfrac{\phi- \theta_x}{\theta_y - \theta_x} b - \dfrac{\theta_x}{\theta_y- \theta_x} (j + q) - \dfrac{1- \theta_x}{\theta_y - \theta_x} &\geq  u \\
    j+ q - (1 + \kappa)b &\leq \frac{1}{\delta } \\
\dfrac{1}{\tau( \gamma+ \omega\kappa)} \geq b\\
\end{align*}

What I know is that all my greek parameters should be between 0 and 1, $\theta_y < \theta_x$ and that all variables are positive.

Comment: As written, there is only $j$ as a variable which seems to be a scalar. As is, it is a linear problem.

Comment: Greek letters are parameters, latin letters are variables?

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni, yes that is right, my focus is though also on $\chi$, which is unknown and I would like to estimate

Comment: You could perform a dichotomy on $t$ with the following feasibility problem: $min_{j,q,b,u} \ 0$ under the constraints $j/\lambda - u \leq tu$ (if $u > 0$) and your other constraints.

Comment: @Marc Dinh could you elaborate a bit more ? what do you refer to as t? Is it a way to linearize somewhat the problem?

Comment: I am denoting your current constraints as $L(j,q,b,u)$ which are linear. Set a value of $t$. If the set $Q = \{(j,q,b,u) | j/(u\lambda) - 1 \leq t \ \text{and} \ L(j,b,qu) \}$ is non empty, then the optimal value of your problem is less than $t$. If however, the set $Q$ is empty, the optimal value of your problem is higher than $t$. I only wrote the non emptiness of $Q$ as a feasibility problem when $u > 0$. You would need to consider the case $u<0$.